# prettyPhoto, "title" and tooltips

Tags: jquery, prettyphoto

In prettyPhoto, how can I have the photo description come from something other than `"title"` (added to `<a>` tag surrounding the `<img>`)? When hovering over the image, it displays ugly html on my website that I only want to be seen and displayed by prettyPhoto when it opens (hence it contains html), but not as a tooltip.

One thought I had was to plug into an event but the only one relevant is changepicturecallback, and I can't figure out how to access the current photo element from that.

Maybe it's something in jQuery itself but I'm a little lost as to where to find it.

Any idea would help.

Thanks,
Igor

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hopefully this isnt to late to answer your question, but i had to modify the pretty photo code recently to do just what you are asking.

there is a line that sets the description from the 'title' attribute of the anchor. You can change it to get the description from wherever you want. I decided to create a <p> tag under the anchor that stores the description.

To change where the description comes from, you have to modify pretty photos source. find the line that looks like this:

```
pp_descriptions = (isSet) ? jQuery.map(matchedObjects, function(n, i){ if($(n).attr('rel').indexOf(theRel) != -1) return ($(n).attr('title')) ? $(n).attr('title') : ""; }) : $.makeArray($(this).attr('title'));
```

it should be on line 152, atleast as of version 3.1.3. Just use a find and replace tool to search for "pp_descriptions."

change it to this:

```
pp_descriptions = (isSet) ? jQuery.map(matchedObjects, function(n, i){ if($(n).attr('rel').indexOf(theRel) != -1) return ($(n).find('p').text()) ? $(n).find('p').text() : ""; }) : $.makeArray($(this).find('p').text());
```

changing the "(this).attr('title')" to ".find('p').text()" will locate a <p> tag in the anchor instead of using the "title" attribute. You will probably want to hide the <p> tag with CSS so it doesnt display on your site.

now the html markup should look like this:

```
<a href="path/to/your/big-image.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto">
    <p>This is the Description</p>
    <img src="path/to/your/small-image.jpg" alt="caption text" />
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's been a while but it's still relevant, I will surely try it!

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem. But in my case only first word was displayed, as there was missing a double quotation marks in HTML markup, in this case, make sure that there is **title=** markup in your HTML and is **quoted**:

```
<a title="Your Title Quoted" href="path/to/your/big-image.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto">
    <img src="path/to/your/small-image.jpg" alt="caption text" />
</a>
```

Hope this will help too.

Answer (score 1):

I was also experiencing this problem and found this article which really helped me:

[Using HTML Formatting in PrettyPhoto Captions](http://blog.karenbryan.co.uk/2013/07/prettyphoto-how-to-make-your-captions.html)

I know this question has already been answered, but i believe this method allows for more freedom in terms of formatting.

**Quote from article:**

> Open the jquery.prettyPhoto.js file from your site and locate the line
> that contains the following code:
>
> pp_descriptions=isSet?jQuery.map(o,function(t,n){if(e(t).attr(settings.hook).indexOf(theRel)!=-1)return
> e(t).attr("title")?e(t).attr("title"):""}):e.makeArray(e(this).attr("title"));

And then replace it with the 'alt' attribute:

> pp_descriptions=isSet?jQuery.map(o,function(t,n){if(e(t).attr(settings.hook).indexOf(theRel)!=-1)return
> e(t).attr("alt")?e(t).attr("alt"):""}):e.makeArray(e(this).attr("alt"));

This works great, you can use "h2" tags and "p" tags to format your caption.  **BUT** this does not allow the page to be validated by the [W3 Validator](https://validator.w3.org).

So instead of using the 'alt' attribute, i simply replaced it with the'aria-label' attribute and voila! It works as expected and allows the page to be validated.

**Example Code:**

```
<a href="path/to/your/big-image.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto" title="This is the native tooltip" aria-label="<h2> This is a caption.</h2> This caption has formatting and does not interfere with the native tooltips.">
    <img src="path/to/your/small-image.jpg" alt="alt-text" />
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is great however if I wish to include break tags 
 or accent titles with the  tag this information doesn't seem to work or else it breaks the functionality.  I can't believe pretty photo would make it this difficult for tooltips to be disabled.....

Who really wants their description to be highlighted with all that code? :P

Comment: K this took me forever to find and I hope it helps all those who are trying to do this. I found that if you add another title into the <img> tag it will force overwrite the ugly html title description. 

For example: 
a href="LINK TO YOUR VIDEO" title="YOUR DESCRIPTION" rel="prettyPhoto"><img src="IMAGE PATH"  **title="THIS TITLE WILL NOW BE DISPLAYED AS THE TOOLTIP"** alt="PUT TITLE OF VIDEO HERE" 
 
Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Please convert you comment into an answer. It should be the accepted one. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Thank-you Kyle!!!!! That really drove me crazy and finally you showed me the way. :)  I'd like to add if you don't want any tooltip to show up, just add a blank space to the img title, ie: title=" " otherwise it ignores it and goes back to the anchor title.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

when you use *tipsy.js*, can neeed to only exchanage "title" attribute to "original-title" in *jquery.prettyPhoto.js*.

like this:

```
pp_descriptions=(isSet)?jQuery.map(matchedObjects,function(n,i){if($(n).attr('rel').indexOf(theRel)!=-1)return($(n).attr('original-title'))?$(n).attr('original-title'):"";}):$.makeArray($(this).attr('original-title'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on what Mitchell said:

I used .html() instead of .text() because I used nested styled spans :

```
<span class="popup_text_cont">
      <span class="popup_caption_cont">
        <span class="popup_detail">
          <span class="popup_caption">Client</span>
          <span class="popup_basic_info">Playhouse Square Foundation</span>
        </span>
        <span class="popup_detail">
          <span class="popup_caption">Project</span>
          <span class="popup_basic_info">Broadway Buzz eNewsletter</span>
        </span>
        <span class="popup_detail">
          <span class="popup_caption">Skills</span>
          <span class="popup_basic_info">HTML, CSS</span>
        </span>
      </span>
      <span class="popup_description">
        Designed and implemented a templated eNewsletter that was distributed to theatergoers and Playhouse Square sponsors.
      </span>
    </span>
```

Replace (what was line 155 for me in the uncompressed version) with something like this.

```
if($(n).attr(settings.hook).indexOf(theRel) != -1) return ($(n).find('span.popup_text_cont').html()) ? $(n).find('span.popup_text_cont').html() : ""; }) : $.makeArray($(this).find('span.popup_text_cont').html());
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this

`font-size: 0px !important;`